# How to determine whether it is EOF when using getline() in c++?

Tags: c++, stream

```
string s;
getline(cin,s);

while (HOW TO WRITE IT HERE?)
{
    inputs.push_back(s);    
    getline(cin,s);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since I'm too lazy to give a full answer today, I'll just paste what the really useful bot in ##c++ on Freenode has to say:

> Using "while (!stream.eof()) {}" is almost certainly wrong. Use the stream's state as the tested value instead: while (std::getline(stream, str)) {}. For further explanation see http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.5

In other words, your code should be

```
string s;

while (getline(cin, s))
{
    inputs.push_back(s);    
}
```

Comment: +1. One of the (sadly few) times in C++ where the right choice is straightforward and idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

```
string s;
getline(cin,s);

while (!cin.eof)
{
        inputs.push_back(s);    
        getline(cin,s);
}
```

Comment: Yes it works and yes it answers the question as stated, but I like coppro's much better I'm afraid. As well as being simpler and more maintainable, coppro's answer will correctly exit if some other I/O error occurs.

Comment: You are right.  I didnt got past the "know when its eof" part.