# Does finishing a file with an empty line serve any purpose?

Tags: file, line

I've been watching Gary Bernhardt's 'Destroy All Software' screencasts, and I notice he invariably has a blank line at the end of every file he works on. Is there a reason to do that?

I'm not referring to whether the file ends with a newline/carriage-return/etc, but rather to an actual visible blank line. If viewed in Vim with line-numbers, this

```
1 code and stuff
2 more code
3
~
~
```

as opposed to

```
1 code and stuff
2 more code
~
~
~
```

Maybe it's just a preference, or a style thing, but I wondered if it's to prevent compile/interpreter errors or something.

Comment: While there may be a few (buggy) tools that explicitly require a blank line at the end, it is generally a *preference* and *not a general requirement*. A more subtle difference is if the file ends in a new-line at all or not; it must always (even if followed by white-space) when introducing a trailing empty line/extra newline.

Answer (score 0):

Some programs will always add an extra line to the end of a program.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505204/c-process-file-blank-line-at-the-end-of-file) for details.